# $scope value is not getting updated in controller, only works when i press refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
   .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout',
      function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.domainModal.show();
        });

        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.loginModal.show();
        });

$scope.baseURL = $localStorage.getObject('baseURL', '{}');
        $http.get($scope.baseURL.url+"Stuff/").success(
          function(response) {
            $scope.stuff = response;
          },
```

For some reason, baseURL.url doesn't work unless I press refresh on the browser using ionic serve --lab.
Basically, I have two modals, the first the domainModal which sets the baseURL.url, and a login modal. So the user picks the baseURL, and then that URL gets used to call baseURL.url+"/Stuff". However, it doesn't work straight away. The baseURL.url is also stored in local storage, but when i get this from local storage the URL comes out with random numbers and the word object.
Anyways, if the baseURL.url is set, then it will only work once i press refresh on the web browser, I think because it's already read the entire controller before it's finished with the domainModal.show();

Comment: Can you post the code where you set `baseUrl.url` ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i had to put the two modals into a new controller like so:

```
function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.domainModal.show();
    });

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.loginModal.show();
    });`
```

Why that is I do not know. All I know is that the whole controller is read when it loads, it doesn't wait for the user to finish with each modal before going on to do the next line. If there is a way of doing that, I sure would like to know.